# Why does an Oracle Union create a duplicate in SSIS?

Tags: oracle, ssis, union

In PLSQL I run:

```
truncate table MyOracleTableName;
commit work;

insert into MyOracleTablename
select a,b,c,trunc(sysdate) as datadate
from AnotherOracleTableName
where there is a ton of nasty criteria

union
select a,b,c,trunc(sysdate) as datadate from AnotherOracleTableName
where there is a ton of different nasty criteria;
commit work;
```

In PLSQL Developer this inserts one row.
When I run the SQL (without the semi colons and the commit work statements) in SSIS, I get a primary key violation from MyOracleTableName.

I have validated that the truncate from SSIS is committed in Oracle.

When I run the  SQL above in PLSQL Developer and replace the union with union all, I see a second row and the insert fails for a PK violation. As it should with a union all allowing the duplicate.

This is currently part of an SSIS 2005 package using MSDAORA where it works just fine. I am now re-writing in SSIS 2008 using Native OLE DB providor for Oracle.

I cannot use MSDAORA in my new environment. Is this a driver issue and is there a work around other than breaking these into multiple statements where the second inserts only what is not already in MyOracleTableName?

Regards.

Comment: Do a `MERGE INTO MyOracleTablename...` based on the `SELECT....UNION ....SELECT`, this should avoid the problem. Although, `UNION` should avoid any duplicate rows.

Comment: Annjawn, the merge into still requires that I split out my SQL into two statements and insert where there is no match. I was trying to avoid that as it doubles the SSIS package. Thank you though. It was an interesting ride trying it out.

Comment: Thank you Nicholas for formatting my code.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the problem after dinner.

The Primary key constraint is a composite key on columns A and B. The Union de-dups on columns a,b,c and the date. In Oracle the trunc(sysdate) returns mm/dd/yyyy. In SSIS the trunc(sysdate) is being parsed out to the second or milisecond. This results in two unique rows (to SQL Server and Microsoft) due to the timestamp, and then attempts to insert duplicate rows where columns a,b, and c are duplicated.

The solution is this:

```
truncate table MyOracleTableName;
commit work;

insert into MyOracleTablename
select a.*,
       trunc(sysdate) as datadate
from(
select a,b,c
from AnotherOracleTableName
where there is a ton of nasty criteria

union
select a,b,c from AnotherOracleTableName
where there is a ton of different nasty criteria) a

commit work;
```

This allows the union to kill the duplicate and runs the trunc(sysdate) once thereby presenting the single row to my primary key constraint.

Thank you.